# Redirecting slug as a parameter for non-files

Tags: .htaccess

I have urls like `/s/30ec3629` which I want to redirect to `/s/somefile.php?s=30ec3629`.

There are other files in that same directory, and if a file exists for a given request I don't want it redirected (i.e. I wouldn't want `/u/some_img.gif` redirected to `/u/somefile.php?s=some_img.gif`). This redirect should only occur within the `/s/` directory.

What is the `.htaccess` rewrite rule I would need for this?

Comment: I warn you that people here don't like asking before trying :|

Comment: Oh I've tried. My attempts at htaccess rewrite rules turn into very ugly messes and kludges and usually produce 500 server internal errors. You really don't want to see the mess I wrote trying to get this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in the htaccess file in your /s/ directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /s/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ somefile.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Do I put this into `/s/.htaccess`, or into `/.htaccess`. I only want the slug redirection to occur within the `/s/` directory, but your code is producing a 404. It works correctly if there's an existing file.

Comment: @Erics sorry, I must have misread your question, see the edit

Comment: Mea culpa, I could have been clearer. The new code works wonderfully, thanks!